# Why those array extensions are not available at run time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to have simple methods for working with arrays so I write this extension class:

```
export class ArrayType<T extends IEntity> extends Array<T> {
  add(item: T) {
    this.push(item);
  }
  remove(item: T) {
    console.log(item);
    const index = this.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id);
    this.splice(index, 1);
  }
  update(item: T) {
    const index = this.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id);
    this.splice(index, 1, item);
  }
}

export interface IEntity {
  id: number;
}
```

then I try to use this methods in my angular application like this:

```
export class DepartmentListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public service: DepartmentService) { }

  items: ArrayType<Department>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe(x => this.items = x);
  }

  onDelete(item: Department) {
    this.items.remove(item);
    this.service.delete(item.id);
  }
  onUpdate(item: Department) {
    this.items.update(item);
    this.service.update(item.id, item);
  }
  onAdd(item: Department) {
    const id = this.service.add(item);
    item.id = id;
    this.items.add(item);
  }
}
```

I get this error at runtime :

[image]

I am a beginer with typescript/javascript and angular.

Can you please help me fix this issue?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: what is x here?

Comment: x is `ArrayType<Department>`

Comment: Then it should work.Can you try `console.log(this.items)`  in onAdd() function?

Comment: if I'm not using my extension, the application works fine

Comment: also you need to define `add()` as `function add()`

Comment: `console.log(this.items)` called before 'this.items.add' is showing me the items from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript does not convert types just because you declared `this.service.getAll()` method to return promise/observable of type `ArrayType`.

I believe that in your service you have call to your API like

```
this._http.get<ArrayType<Department>>()
```

And you are under false impression that parameter in your subscription will be of that type. It is not. Its an ordinary `Array`.

To fix this you can `map` your http request:

```
this._http.get<Array<Department>>().map(x => new ArrayType(x))
```

this will require a constructor for your `ArrayType` that takes an array and copy it into base or you can change your class from derived from array into wrapper over an array this will not require copping of data.

The reason this is like this is typescript is different form other languages like C# and Java it is not enforcing types in runtime it just allows you to make assumptions on values returned from methods and than using those assumptions it will help you create your code.

---

To make your `ArrayType` work with my suggestion above you need constructor:

```
export class ArrayType<T extends IEntity> extends Array<T> {
    constructor(value:Array<T>){ 
        super(...value);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ArrayType.prototype);
    }
//...
```

arrays are special kind of objects so the additional line in constructor is required you can read TS [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work) part about it. This requires TS 2.1 I believe. It also will not work for IE 10 and prior.

The other way around it would be to make a wrapper over an array that can be painful with copping all methods of array that you need.

Comment: indeed I was making the assumption that typescript will cast the return type to my `ArrayType`, if is not like that, then I don not know how to implement such a constructor to cast from normal array in ArrayType. Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @LucianBumb I've extended my answer.

Comment: Do I need some namespaces? the typescript is complayining about `super(value)` and 'SuperArray`, and give this error `ERROR in src/app/_jsExtentions/appExtensions.ts(4,11): error TS2345: Argument of type 'T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
src/app/_jsExtentions/appExtensions.ts(5,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SuperArray'.`

Comment: Yes you need the `...` before the `value` in super call.

Comment: still have this error: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SuperArray'.`

Comment: sorry about that it should be `ArrayType` instead